# My Tizen app flickers upon tapping

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-emulator

I'm building a JavaScript Tizen app for Gear S2
In an earlier stage of development I considered using Angular, but I just ignored the possibility entirely because ng-click events made the screen flicker.

I kept building the app without any issues, my click event worked fine!
Until
I incorporated jQuery mobile
and suddenly my app now flickers when I "tap" the emulator.
I tried binding the event in 3 different manners, with the same result:

```
window.addEventListener("click", callback); // way 1
$(document).bind("click", changeMode); // way 2
$(document).bind("tap", changeMode); // way 3
```

does anyone have a clue of why this might be happening?

Comment: it gets far more frustrating when I comment the jquery mobile include and it WORKS again!

Answer (score 0):

When do you bind the click event? Maybe you add the listener multiple times, so your Callback is also triggered multiple times.
Also why add the click listener to the window/document instead of a proper element?

I would also prefer to use ".on()" and ".off()" instead of bind.

Maybe you can share some of your code so we can "see" the problem?

Comment: its added 1 time. Also I have multiple elements in the app that need to respond trigerring the same function when I click

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my jQuery is a bit rusty. not that I was ever a pro at it but hey

Comment: I fixed the problem by copying a custom swipe event "library" I found. I had to fix many things about the code because it was a mess that had no beauty to it whatsoever. BUT it worked

Comment: The very same code runs fine without including jquery mobile And flickers when jquery mobile is added, kind of strange, when I get my hands on my laptop ill share some snippets